# How to add Get.Attribute(src) values into List<string> or am i add values to other list method c#?

Tags: c#, list, selenium, addition, getattribute

I am coding with C# selenium. I need your help. I can find an attribute `src` and can write it. But I need to add these values to an existing List, because I will use it for adding these values to the database. But when I run the provided code, it never updated the List, so it is always empty.

```
// FIND ELEMENT WHICH WILL BE USE FOR GET.ATTRIBUTE(SRC)
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> imageelements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.product-slide"));
List<IWebElement> elements = new List<IWebElement>(imageelements) ;

int a = elements.Count;
string b = Convert.ToString(a);
label5.Text = b;

// LIST FOR STORE THE GET.ATTRIBUTE VALUES
List<string> srclist = new List<string>();
int c = srclist.Count;

int i = 1;
foreach (IWebElement element in elements)
{
    // GET ATRRIBUTE(SRC) OF ELEMENT
    var imagetag = element.FindElement (By.TagName("img"));
    string imagesrc = imagetag.GetAttribute("src");
    
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    // ADDING VALUES TO LIST ------- IT IS MY PROBLEM: VALUES NOT ADDING TO LIST
    srclist.Add(imagesrc);

    label6.Text = "src  " + imagesrc + "   " + c;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    label5.Text = "src islenir" + i;
    
    i++;
    if (a == i) break;
}

label6.Text = ">>>>>" + c;
```

EDIT

```
string currenturl = driver.Url;
        // item Name
        var itemName = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".pr-new-br")).Text;
        // item Price
        var itemPrice = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("prc-dsc")).Text;
        label2.Text = itemName + itemPrice;

        // FIND ELEMENT WHICH WILL BE USE FOR GET.ATTRIBUTE(SRC)
        IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> imageelements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.product-slide"));
        List<IWebElement> elements = new List<IWebElement>(imageelements) ;
        
        int a = elements.Count;
        string b = Convert.ToString(a);
        label5.Text = b;

        
        // LIST FOR STORE THE GET.ATTRIBUTE VALUES
        List<string> srclist = new List<string>();
        int c = srclist.Count;

        int i = 1;
        foreach (IWebElement element in elements)
        {
            
            // GET ATRRIBUTE(SRC) OF ELEMENT
            var imagetag = element.FindElement (By.TagName("img"));
            string imagesrc = imagetag.GetAttribute("src");
            
            
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            // ADDING VALUES TO LIST ------- IT IS MY PROBLEM: VALUES NOT ADDING TO LIST
            srclist.Add(imagesrc);

            label6.Text = "src  " + imagesrc + "   " + c;

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            label5.Text = "src islenir" + i;
            
            i++;
            if (a == i) break;
        }
        int gg = srclist.Count;
        label6.Text = ">>>>>" + gg;



        string combinsrc = string.Join(",", srclist.ToArray());







        string connetionstring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\vsss\veri\veri\excel\veridatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        con = new SqlConnection(connetionstring);
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        // INSERT INTO DATABASE === ALL CORRECTLY INSERTING JUST ---COMBINSRC--- VALUES NOT INSERT
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO urun (ismi, fiyati, link, hiperlink ) VALUES ('" + itemName + "','" + itemPrice + "','" + currenturl + "','" + combinsrc + "')";
        label5.Text = "src alindi";
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I could understand your problem, you think that the `srclist` is never updated, because your variable `c` is always `0`. This is the supposed behavoiur, because you set its value by counting elements in the empty (just created) `List` and never update it.
The solution is easy, so you just can add the following code line after the `srclist.Add(imagesrc);`:

```
c = srclist.Count;
```

This is not the best practice, but it should help you.

Comment: A good point for count c, but problem is when i write list to database(varchar MAX) it shows Null at column . I try but List is empty

Comment: @MknAli, from the provided code block I can't see any other issues that can influence contents of the `List`. Let me suppose that the problems are connected with storing or writing data to the database. Could you please provide some more code?